# How can I run inter-dependent queries alongside a non-DB operation in the same transaction using slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, playback

Given the data model (<- indicating a foreign key dependency)

```
TableA <- TableB <- TableC
   ^                 v
    -----------------
```

I need to execute an api DELETE operation that soft-deletes a row in TableC. This delete must also trigger a call to another service (requiring values from TableA and TableB) if there are no more undeleted TableC entries that reference that row's parent in TableB. If the external call fails, I want to rollback the soft-delete. I want to do all of this in an idiomatic fashion (I'm effectively brand new to scala/slick), and use transactions for the rollback

Based on what I've read, I need to be using for comprehension to assemble the queries, but I'm having issues getting the database operations to gel nicely with the external service call. My original plan was:

```
val select = for {
  tableCRow <- tableBDao.TableQueryC.filter(_.id === idParam)
  tableBRow <- tableBDao.TableQueryB if tableCRow.tableBForeignKey === tableBRow.id
  tableARow <- TableADao.TableQueryA if tableCRow.tableAForeignKey === tableARow.id
  count <- tableBDao.TableQueryC.filter(_.tableBForeignKey === tableBRow.id).map(_.id).countDefined
  _ <- tableBDao.softDeleteRow(idParam)
  _ <- if (count > 1) DBIO.successful(httpRequestService.deleteOtherResource(tableARow.someValue, tableBRow.someValue))
} yield ()
db.run(select.result)
```

But this had problems because I couldn't pass Slick's Rep[T] values to my httpRequestService method. I then tried to break it down into two portions - SELECT first, then DELETE, like so:

```
val select = for {
  tableCRow <- tableBDao.TableQueryC.filter(_.id === idParam)
  tableBRow <- tableBDao.TableQueryB if tableCRow.tableBForeignKey === tableBRow.id
  tableARow <- TableADao.TableQueryA if tableCRow.tableAForeignKey === tableARow.id
  count <- tableBDao.TableQueryC.filter(_.tableBForeignKey === tableBRow.id).map(_.id).countDefined
} yield (tableBRow.date.formatted("yyyy-MM-DD"), tableARow.externalServiceId, count)
val result: Future[Option[(String, Long, Integer)]] = db.run(select.result.headOption)
result.map {
  case None => throw new IllegalArgumentException("exception message")
  case Some(data) =>
    val delete = for {
      _ <- tableBDao.softDeleteRow(idParam)
      _ <- if (data._3 > 1) DBIO.successful(httpRequestService.cancelSchedulerJob(data._2, data._1))
    } yield numRows
    db.run(delete.transactionally)
}
```

But, despite this actually passing IntelliJ IDEA checks, it won't compile as my `count` query returns a Rep[Int], which lacks a `map` function. Additionally, each of my table(A|B|C)Row maps raises an error because they're expecting `slick.lifted.Query[Nothing,Nothing,Seq]` and they're getting `slick.lifted.Query[Nothing,T,Seq]`. Finally, the `db.run` statement doesn't want to use `headOption`, and apparently returns `Any` which doesn't support `map`

halp

Comment: `httpRequestService.deleteOtherResource(tableARow.someValue, tableBRow.someValue)` returns `Future[_]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by finally understanding how slick puts things together in a for-comprehension. I had to pull the count out of the query and into a followup groupby->map function, which accumulated my list of things I wanted to count and THEN counted them as opposed to counting as part of the query. This fixed all the rest of the problems too, as the count query was throwing off the expected return types of everything else.

basically, the solution looked like (thing1 was for a join):

```
val select = (for {
  thing1 <- query1
  thing2 <- query2
  thing3 <- query3
  listToCount <- query4 selecting everything I wanted to count
} yield (thing2, thing3, listToCount))
  .groupBy({
    case (thing2, thing3, listToCount) =>
      (thing2, thing3)
  })
  .map({
    case ((thing2, thing3), list) =>
      (thing2.deliveryDate, thing3.schedulerJobId, list.map(_._3).length)
  })
```